# How do I import scoped CSS in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Does anyone know how to import a scoped CSS file in Vue 3?

I tried including the code in the script tag (seen below) but it just includes the CSS globally. Then I tried adding it to the src attribute for the style tag, which works, but it ignores the styles within the style tag (also seen below).

**Script Tag Include**

```
<script>
import '@/assets/sass/styles.sass'
export default {   
...
```

**Style Tag Include**

```
<style lang="sass" src="@/assets/sass/styles.sass" scoped>
/* wrapper style ignored if I include src */
#wrapper   
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, was able to figure it out right after posting the question. For anyone else having this issue, you can simply call import within your style tag and it will maintain scoped status. Example below ...

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
import '@/assets/sass/styles.sass'
/* wrapper is now recognized */
#wrapper   
...
```

Answer (score 6):

you try for css

```
<style lang="css" scoped src="../../../public/css/company/style.css"></style>
```

Answer (score 3):

@Gnoll Team's answer did not work for me, at least not with with pure css. What worked was dedicated `style` element with `src`, and on top of that you can add second style element with inline css.

```
<style lang="css" scoped src="./style.css"></style>
<style lang="css" scoped>
# more css here
</style>
```

But there is a caveat with scoped css. You can not use CSS custom properties (--*) defined in `:root` selector. Workaround is to use `:first-child` instead and make sure that `<template>` contains single root element.

Answer (score 1):

So that other styles are not ignored, you can use `@import` to import style rules from other stylesheets. The `~@/` characters are used to identify the `src` root of the vue, in this case Vue 3, for other versions of Vue one should check the correct import way.

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
@import '~@/assets/sass/styles.sass';

/* more sass here */
</style>
```

Note the caveat with scoped css explained by @jurijs-kovzels.